Joined object texture problem
Maybe someone knows what the problem is.
I had a workflow like this. I took part 1 and mirrored it to the bottom and then glued it together. but I realize that something went wrong somewhere in the polygons.



could you please be more specific on what is going wrong according to you?

Hello and welcome. Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
